# i am trying to rewrite url for home page and category in webconfig c#

Tags: iis, url-rewrite-module

```
<rule name="Default" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="^(.*)$"/>
   <conditions>
     <add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="\." ignoreCase="false"/>
   </conditions>
   <action type="Rewrite" url="Default.aspx?Alias={R:1}"/>
</rule>
<rule name="Categorys" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.*)$"/>
    <conditions>
       <add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="\." ignoreCase="false"/>
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/Vn/Categorys.aspx?Alias={R:1}"/>
</rule>
```

i want URL:

```
https://domain/ ==>  Default
https://domain/Categorys ==>  Categorys
```

but it only goes to the homepage

can you help me fix it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What does this have to do with C#?

Answer (score 0):

From the above description, it looks like your requirement is to redirect from `https://domain/Category` to `https://domain/Vn/Categorys.aspx?Alias=123`

I could see that your rules does not has correct patterns.

I would suggest you try to make a test with the rule below.

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="rule-4" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="/Vn/Categorys.aspx?Alias={C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
            <conditions>
                            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="/category/(.*)" />
            </conditions>
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Further, you could modify the rule as per your own requirements.